# How to use custom event with typescript in vue-next

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

I have a `Child` component emit a custom event `change`, and listen this event on `Parent` component。

The code is like below

Child.vue

```
<template>
  <button @click="onClick">emit an event</button>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
  import { defineComponent } from 'vue'
  export default defineComponent({
    emits: ['change'],
    setup(props, {emit}) {
       function onClick () {
         emit('change', 'This is string type payload')
       }
       
       return { onClick }
    }
  })
</script>
```

Parent.vue

```
<template>
  <child @change="onChange" />
</template>
<script>
  import { defineComponent } from 'vue'
  import Child from './Child.vue'

  export default defineComponent({
    components: {Child},
    setup(props) {
       function onChange (payload: string) {
           console.log(payload)
       }
       
       return { onChange }
    }
  })
</script>
```

When I use `Child` component in `Parent`, there is no type checking for `change` event handler.

So how to define the custom event type in `Child` component.

Comment: What's the problem exactly? That you don't have type checking on the vue template for component properties? Or that the event doesn't trigger?

Comment: Btw, you're using `onChange` method but you defined `onClick` in the component.

Comment: Yes, I don't have type checking on the vue template，because `Child` does not define the custom event type. @ Kapcash